# Strange extra argument

Tags: python, wxpython

I got the following python code where `printSaved` is called when a button is clicked (using the wx library and python 2.7.2). But when this happens i got a really strange error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./program.py", line 135, in printSaved
    s = self.readSaved()
TypeError: readSaved() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Here is the code

```
  def readSaved():
    f = codecs.open((os.getenv('HOME') +'/Dokument/savefile.txt') ,'r','utf-8')
    l = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return l

  def printSaved(self,event):
    s = self.readSaved()
    for l in s:
      print l
```

I fixed the problem by adding one argument to `readSaved(somethingUseless)` and everything worked fine. My question is what is passed to readSaved and HOW/WHY? Does this have something to do with the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, the object on which a method is called is always passed in explicitly as an argument. This argument is conventionally called `self`.

The correct definition for `readSaved()` as an instance method should have this as the first line:

```
def readSaved(self):
    # ...
```

If you want it to be a module-level function, you should call it as follows:

```
s = readSaved()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this helpt me to understand a litle bit more about python

Answer (score 2):

[Methods are passed the instance as the first argument.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is it defined within a class? I suppose it does, since the second method takes `self`.

If `readSaved` is an instance method, it takes `self` as first parameter as well. If you don't need it, use the `@staticmethod` decorator instead:

```
@staticmethod
def readSaved():
  f = codecs.open((os.getenv('HOME') +'/Dokument/savefile.txt') ,'r','utf-8')
  l = f.readlines()
  f.close()
  return l
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a method -- you're calling it as a method, anyway -- you have to have at least `self` as an argument. When a function is called as a method, the object you call the method through is passed as the first argument to that function.